# displaying value from a many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, entity-relationship

im attempting to display a value from a many to many relationship

in my view im calling the following

```
schedule.opponents.name
```

this code isnt displaying any errors, though its just displaying the word 'Opponent'

on other methods that i have a belongs_to relationship this method seems to have displayed the value i am after

any tips?

```
class Opponent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :schedules
  has_many  :teams
  attr_accessible :name
end


class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :opponents
  has_many :teams
  attr_accessible :location_id, :date, :opponent_id, :time, :for, :against, :event, :team, :home_or_away
```

Comment: Paul, please share your models (or even redacted versions of your models). I could make assumptions, but you haven't provided enough information for a well thought out answer to be given.

Comment: that comment didnt work very well :S

Comment: Your relashionships are messed up. Try Opponent `belongs_to :schedule`  and Schedule `has_many :opponents`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relashionship, you are assuming to have n models to n models. So when you are doing a `schedule.opponents`, you are retrieving and array of objects of `Opponent` model, and because of that, you can't call an attribute of that model.
An easy way to see the problem is to type on your console:

```
schedule.opponents.last.name
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `schedule.opponents`, you are getting an array of all opponents belonging to `schedule`. The array may have zero, one, or multiple elements based upon your data.

Try this:

```
<% @opponents = schedule.opponents %>
<% @opponents.each do |opponent| %>
  <%= opponent.name %><br />
<% end %>
```

Good luck!

Comment: doing as you suggest throws this error SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: opponents.schedule_id: SELECT "opponents".* FROM "opponents"  WHERE "opponents"."schedule_id" = 1

Comment: Try singular opponent inside the loop.

Comment: Can you post your models and field names. It seems like you have not set up the relationships/ fields correctly.